# External Drive Not Showing up Anywhere

Tags: windows, macos, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a Lacie Rugged Drive I'm having issues with. It will continue to sound like it is starting up but won't mount. I can see it listed on my mac under the system report but it will not show up anywhere else including disk utility or running diskutil list. I tried removing the drive from the enclosure and connecting it via a SATA like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08Y8TZX6M) but it continues to make the noise. I am not able to see it anywhere in windows either and the drive as far as I know is formated to APFS. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The drive is likely toast. If the problem was with the original enclosure  it wouldn't do the same with the new adapter. Also keep in mind that even if good it wouldn't appear in Windows file explorer - unsupported filesystem - but would in disk management.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming it's not the drive, then resetting the NVRAM on your Mac can sometimes resolve hardware-related issues.

To do this, leave the drive plugged in and restart your Mac and hold down the Option + Command + P + R keys simultaneously until you hear the startup sound for the second time. Then release the keys and see if the drive mounts.

Comment: Not seen on Windows PC either so it's not a local RAM issue.

Comment: Blowing the NVRAM almost never fixes anything, especially when what you're trying to fix is not an NVRAM parameter. It's one of those interwebz memes that just will not die. NVRAM stores chime volume, screen resolution, time zone information, and boot drive.

Comment: It was early hours of the morning and I was making a suggestion that it could be a display issue, but with it not showing on windows I highly doubt that. However, had that not been the case, my suggestion would have been valid. It's most likely a shot disk.

Comment: @Tetsujin By resetting the NVRAM/PRAM, you are clearing certain stored settings such as display resolution, startup disk selection, volume settings, and other system-related parameters. It was a suggestion and one where I said "SOMETIMES HELPS" I've had drives that wouldn't show as mounted but after clearing it, they did because it was a display issue. It helps resolve communication or configuration issues between the Mac and the external device.

Comment: Sorry, but knee-jerk 'blow PRAM, reset SMC' never gets upvotes from me. It's just interwebz meme, usually applied for no reason & makes no sense.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm not here for upvotes dude. I was just making an "on-the-fly" early hours of the morning suggestion to try and HELP the op. I've explained my reasons for suggesting it, and I said it "SOMETIMES HELPS" because it all depended on it being a display issue.

Comment: @Tetsujin Also, I do agree its often used incorrectly, but that was not the case I do know exactly what it does.

Comment: This isn't reddit. You may be keen, obviously new & haven't yet developed the thick skin required to participate long-term here. You have to get used to people not being positively responsive to what really should have been a comment rather than an answer - it was a speculative guess rather than an actual 'fix'. We like actual fixes here. Solid, expansive answers that clearly seek to solve the user's issue. Anything of a 'hey, try this' should be a comment, not an answer. Sorry to have raised ire, all that was intended was to point out this is not likely to work in the OP's situation.

Comment: @Tetsujin Due to my current reputation level on the platform, I am unable to leave comments and can only provide answers. Rest assured, I'm here to assist anyone to the best of my abilities. While I acknowledge your perspective, it's essential to maintain a respectful demeanour and to come to a full understanding before making assumptions. Have a pleasant evening!

Comment: @Tetsujin I will wait until I can comment to make suggestions. Have a pleasant evening!

Comment: I upvoted one of your other answers that deserved it. You only need 50 rep to be able to comment anywhere, so it's but a small hurdle relatively. Stick around & enjoy. Don't let the grumpy ones get to you, there are a lot of nerds [like me] on the autism scale who don't do 'polite' very well, we just do 'information' :))

Comment: @Tetsujin No worries at least I learned something, and now know it's better to comment with any suggestions. I'll save the answers for when I'm 100%. Thank you.